# Qlik sense, Index field/function

Tags: qliksense, tableau-desktop

In tableau I had measure index which was created simple like 'index()' and that's it
I need to recreate all dashboards from Tableau to Qlik Sense,
and I dont know how to create this Index() field?
I tried by putting index in data load editor, but it won't work.
Thank you in advance
ena

Answer (score 0):

In Qlik there a couple of functions that can return index/id:

- [RecNo()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/CounterFunctions/RecNo.htm#)
- [RowNo()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/CounterFunctions/RowNo.htm)

The main difference between the two is that `RowNo()` do not count records that are excluded by `Where` clause and it is not reset when the table is concatenated